# bigcouch stuck if one from three nodes down

Tags: node.js, couchdb, bigcouch

i use bigcouch as my project...
i open 3 node ( default )
everything fine until one node suddenly down ( one server crash )

why if one node down, input process stuck...?
i read the documentation...
i try to set N = 1 ( replicate constant ) , R = 1 (read qourum constant ), and W = 1 (write qourum constant)...

i think my conf mean if 1 write and 1 replicate happen to server that's enaugh to return 201 status.

and then i made issue in bigcouch github..
i get the answer that i must set setting to default...
i already set the setting into default but bigcouch still stuck if one from three node down...

this 3 node i input in "nodes" database:

> bigcouch@bigserver1.server1
>
> bigcouch@bigserver2.server2
>
> bigcouch@bigserver3.server3

and this error i get if i create a database via futon on one node down condition...

> > {timeout,[{{shard,undefined,'bigcouch@bigserver1.server1',undefined,undefined, #Ref}, ok}, {{shard,undefined,'bigcouch@bigserver2.server2',undefined,undefined, #Ref}, ok}, {{shard,undefined,'bigcouch@bigserver3.server3',undefined,undefined, #Ref}, nil}]}

need 10 minutes until this error come out...
this happen to with my node.js apps, and made my node.js apps stuck for 10 minutes

Comment: problem solved.... if i input database bigcouch will stuck... but if document input bigcouch not stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of BigCouch 0.3. In 0.4 you will be able to create and delete databases as long as a majority of nodes is online.

Comment: thanks... what if i use bigcouch 0.4 i can create database even 1 node (from 3 node) down..?